# How to compress pdf file generated by XeLaTeX?

Tags: xetex, pdftex, pdf, compiling

I hope you can help me.
I am new to latex and perhaps I am not yet capable of creating well optimized code.
I am creating a file pdf full of figures and tables to send to my professor, who ask for a maximum file size of 500 KB.
I use OverLeaf and as a complier I used pdfLaTeX.
PdfLaTex generated me a file (about 60 pages) with a size of 1.5MB. With pdfsizeopt I've reached 647 KB.
XeLaTeX generates me the same file, but with a size of 1 MB. But with pdfsizeopt I have reached only 630 KB ...
The images I use were created with MatLab in pdf. So they are in vector graphics. Maximum size 17-20 KB with a mean size of 2-3KB each.
My professor demands a file of 500 KB.
He gave no instructions on how to do it.
Would you guys know how to help me?
I do not know what to do.
thanks a lot

Comment: Have you tried "Open a PDF in Acrobat DC. Choose File > Reduce File Size or Compress PDF" ? There are also lots of free web sites which reduces PDF files sizes if you do not have adobe PDF installed. Just google "optimize pdf size" and such.

Comment: did you compare the file size without the pictures? (you can use the draft  option to suppress them)

Comment: @Nasser, yeah I've tried but the compression by using online tools (and Acrobat) is even worse than using pdfsizeopt.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, it drops to 160 Kb....

Comment: I doubt that you can compress more (well you could try to zip the file ...). And the size of your pictures is not large. Ask your professor what you should do.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, I tried asking what to do specifically, but he just told me that there is a function...

Comment: well files get larger wtih content. You can't avoid to add a few bytes with every image and character, they don't consist of empty air. If he knows how to get a smaller file he should tell you, if he doesn't know he shouldn't claim it can be done.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, I know perfectly well, but he wants files smaller than 500 KB because he also said that, in his book, a chapter in TeX with pictures takes up less than 200 KB... I don't really know what to do...

Comment: if the images are what making the file large, you could try reducing the quality of images. What format of images are you using?

Comment: well ask him to show you the code of the chapter and and the pictures and ask him how he compiles so that you can compare the methods (and check if he has the same number of pictures and pages).

Comment: @Nasser, .pdf exported by matlab. They are vectorial imges.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, thanks for the advices, I am gonna try...

Comment: There is no way to change the size label of the file? To fake it...

Comment: Solved by changing the pics in png. Drop of quality but at least I am under 500 KB